metaplex umi updateAuthority Error: Update Authority given does not match
BACKEND:
    const wallet_pubkey = new PublicKey(wallet_pubkey_string);
    const wallet2 = Keypair.fromSecretKey(bs58.decode(wallet2_key));
    const amount = 0.5;
    
    const signer_wallet = createNoopSigner(fromWeb3JsPublicKey(wallet_pubkey));
    const update_auth = createNoopSigner(fromWeb3JsPublicKey(wallet2_key.publicKey));
    
    const umi = createUmi(rpcUrl);
    umi.use(mplTokenMetadata());
    umi.use(signerIdentity(signer_wallet))
    const umiMintSigner = generateSigner(umi);
    
    const nftData = {
        mint: umiMintSigner,
        updateAuthority: update_auth, //the problem is in this line
        isMutable: true,
        name: 'test',
        symbol: 'test',
        uri: url,
        sellerFeeBasisPoints: percentAmount(10,2),
        creators: creators,
        tokenOwner: fromWeb3JsPublicKey(wallet_pubkey),
    };
    const transferData = {
        destination: fromWeb3JsPublicKey(wallet2.publicKey),
        amount: sol(amount),
    };
    let transaction = await transactionBuilder()
        .add(createNft(umi, nftData))
        .add(transferSol(umi, transferData))
        .setFeePayer(signer_wallet)
        .useV0()
        .buildWithLatestBlockhash(umi);
    
    const web3jsVersionedTransaction = toWeb3JsTransaction(transaction);
        web3jsVersionedTransaction.sign([Keypair.fromSecretKey(umiMintSigner.secretKey), Keypair.fromSecretKey(wallet2.secretKey)]);
    const web3jsVersionedTransactionSerialized = web3jsVersionedTransaction.serialize()
    const transaction_serialize_string = Buffer.from(web3jsVersionedTransactionSerialized).toString('base64');

FRONTEND:
On the frontend, the transaction is signed by the wallet wallet_pubkey.
    if (window.solana && window.solana.isPhantom) {
      try {
        const connection = new Connection(url, "confirmed");
        const transaction_array = Buffer.from(transactionBuildValue, 'base64');
        const decodedTransaction = VersionedTransaction.deserialize(transaction_array);
        const { blockhash } = await connection.getLatestBlockhash();
        decodedTransaction.recentBlockhash = blockhash;
        const signedTransaction = await window.solana.signTransaction(decodedTransaction);
        const signature = await connection.sendRawTransaction(signedTransaction.serialize());
        await connection.confirmTransaction(signature, 'processed');
        return { success: true, signature };
        console.log(signature);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    }

I get an error when trying to confirm a transaction via wallet.
Error:
Error: Simulation failed.  Message: Transaction simulation failed:
Error processing Instruction 2: custom program error: 0x7.   
Logs:  [  
"Program log: Instruction: SetAuthority",
"Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 3250 of 692177 compute units",
"Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success",
"Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s consumed 117798 of 799706 compute units", "Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s success",
"Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s invoke [1]",
"Program log: IX: Mint",
"Program log: Update Authority given does not match",
"Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s consumed 31390 of 681908 compute units",
"Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s failed: custom program error: 0x7"
].

If I don't use the string updateAuthority: update_auth in nftData and i don't use Keypair.fromSecretKey(wallet2.secretKey) in web3jsVersionedTransaction.sign  then the problem doesn't occur and the code works correctly.
How to fix the problem and add updateAuthority correctly?

Try setting the update auth in a new instruction
async function updateUpdateAuthority() {
    const mint = publicKey(""); // update with mint address

    await updateV1(umi, {
        mint,
        authority: umi.identity,
        newUpdateAuthority: publicKey(""), // new update auth
        primarySaleHappened: true,
        isMutable: true,
    }).sendAndConfirm(umi);
}

updateUpdateAuthority().then().catch();


yes, but is it possible to do this in my transaction?

I don't think you can with the create helpers. I am also not sure if composing with the individual instructions, create and mint will work, but give it a try, I might be wrong.
